Testing code for infinite scrolling functionality using IntersectionObserver
I'm currently working on a React + TypeScript + React Query project, and I'm having trouble writing test code!

The first piece of code is the MainGrid component, where I am using a custom hook called useInfiniteScroll for infinite scrolling.

The second piece of code is the custom hook itself. Based on these two pieces of code, I've written a test for the infinite scroll functionality in the MainGrid component.

However, the test keeps failing, and I can't figure out why. The test fails at expect(IntersectionObserverMock).toHaveBeenCalled(), and it seems like the IntersectionObserverMock, which is supposed to mock IntersectionObserver, is not being called. When I check const instance = IntersectionObserverMock.mock.instances[0] in the console, it outputs undefined.


Could anyone help me with this issue? I would really appreciate any assistance!
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from "styled-components";
import useInfiniteScroll from '../hooks/use-infinitescroll';
import LazyLoadingImage from './LazyLoading';
import PlaceholderImg from '../assets/images/placeholderImg.svg';
import { productQuery } from '../hooks/useProductQuery';

function MainGrid() {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const { data, hasNextPage, fetchNextPage } = productQuery.useGetProducts();
    const target = useInfiniteScroll({
        hasNextPage,
        fetchNextPage,
    })

    return (
        <Container>
            {
                data?.pages.flat().map((p, i) => {
                    return <div key={p?.product_id}>
                        <LazyLoadingImage
                            src={p?.image}
                            onError={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLImageElement>) => {
                                e.target.onerror = null; 
                                e.target.src = p.image 
                                e.target.width = 380;
                                e.target.height = 380;
                            }}
                            alt={p?.product_name}
                            onClick={() => navigate(`/detail/${p?.product_id}`)}
                            placeholderImg={PlaceholderImg}
                        />
                        <p className='product-name'>{p?.store_name}</p>
                        <p className='product'>{p?.product_name}</p>
                        <span className='product-price'>{p?.price?.toLocaleString()}</span>
                        <span>원</span>
                    </div>
                })
            }
            <div ref={target} data-testid='scroll-target'></div>
        </Container>
    )
}

This is the MainGrid component.
import { InfiniteQueryObserverResult } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

type IntersectionObserverProps = {
    hasNextPage?: boolean | false;
    fetchNextPage?: () => Promise<InfiniteQueryObserverResult>;
    onIntersection?: (entry: IntersectionObserverEntry[], observer: IntersectionObserver) => void;
}

function useInfiniteScroll({ hasNextPage, fetchNextPage, onIntersection }: IntersectionObserverProps) {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const handleIntersect: IntersectionObserverCallback = useCallback(([entry]: IntersectionObserverEntry[], observer: IntersectionObserver) => {
        if (onIntersection) {
            onIntersection(entry[0], observer);
        }
        if (entry?.isIntersecting && hasNextPage) {
            fetchNextPage();
        }
    }, [fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, onIntersection]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let observer: IntersectionObserver;
        if (ref.current) {
            observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, { threshold: 0.6, });
            observer.observe(ref.current);
        }
        return () => observer && observer.disconnect();
    }, [ref, handleIntersect]);

    return ref;
}

export default useInfiniteScroll

This is the useInfiniteScroll custom hook.
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import MainGrid from "../MainGrid";
import { act } from '@testing-library/react';
import { productQuery } from "../../hooks/useProductQuery";
import { InfiniteData, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, UseInfiniteQueryResult } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { Product } from '../types/product';
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import useInfiniteScroll from '../../hooks/use-infinitescroll';

jest.mock('../../hooks/use-infinitescroll', () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(() => ({ current: null })),
}));

jest.mock('../../hooks/useProductQuery', () => ({
    productQuery: {
        useGetProducts: jest.fn(),
    }
}));
const mockedUseGetProducts = jest.mocked(productQuery.useGetProducts);

const IntersectionObserverMock = jest.fn((callback, options = {}) => {
    const instance = {
        thresholds: Array.isArray(options.threshold) ? options.threshold : [options.threshold],
        root: options.root,
        rootMargin: options.rootMargin,
        observe: jest.fn(),
        unobserve: jest.fn(),
        disconnect: jest.fn(),
        trigger: () => callback([{ isIntersecting: true }], instance)
    };
    return instance;
});

(global as any).IntersectionObserver = IntersectionObserverMock;

const mockProduct = {
    pages: [
        Array.from({ length: 15 }, (_, i) => ({
            product_id: i,
            image: `image_url${i}`,
            product_name: `Product ${i}`,
            store_name: `Stroe ${i}`,
            price: 1000 + i
        }))
    ],
};

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

describe('MainGrid Component', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    })

    it('should render products and load more on scroll', async () => {
        const fetchNextPage = jest.fn();
        const hasNextPage = true;

        const ref = { current: null };
        (useInfiniteScroll as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(ref);

        mockedUseGetProducts.mockReturnValue({
            data: {
                pages: mockProduct.pages,
                pageParams: [1],
            },
            hasNextPage,
            fetchNextPage
        } as unknown as UseInfiniteQueryResult<InfiniteData<Product[], unknown>, Error>);

        render(
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <MemoryRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/" element={<MainGrid />} />
                    </Routes>
                </MemoryRouter>
            </QueryClientProvider>
        );
       
            ref.current = screen.getByTestId('scroll-target')
            useInfiniteScroll({ hasNextPage, fetchNextPage });

            const instance = IntersectionObserverMock.mock.instances[0];
            if (!instance) {
                console.error("IntersectionObserverMock instance is undefined");
            } else {
                instance.trigger();    
            }
            expect(IntersectionObserverMock).toHaveBeenCalled();

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(fetchNextPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});

And this is the test code I wrote.
I've been searching for the cause for days, but I just can't figure it out. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me.

It isn't clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but the IntersectionObserver is not being created because in your test you are mocking the hook use-infinitescroll, which is the custom hook that contains the logic to create the IntersectionObserver.

Why does mocking useInfiniteScroll not create an IntersectionObserver? Then what should be mocked? I tried to mock the useInfiniteScroll custom hook and set global.IntersectionObserver to use the mocked version of useInfiniteScroll before running the tests. Since MainGrid uses this hook, I thought that when it's rendered, useInfiniteScroll would be triggered through the ref, which would then create an IntersectionObserver. This would, in turn, execute the mocked IntersectionObserverMock function that I set up.
